# AdvancedSearch on Outlook through Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to perform an advancedsearch in my mailbox through Excel VBA but i don't know how to make a case-insensitive search. 
Here is my Filter:

```
       Filter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%Pending%'" & _
     "AND urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription LIKE '%" & ISIN & "%'" & _
     "AND urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription LIKE '%" & StlDate & "%'"
```

I tried with this filter but it does not work. I can't find the emails with "PENDING" in the subject. I also tried with this filter:

```
 Filter = "(urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%Pending%'" & _
     "AND urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription LIKE '%" & ISIN & "%'" & _
     "AND urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription LIKE '%" & StlDate & "%' ) OR " & _
     "(urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%PENDING%'" & _
     "AND urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription LIKE '%" & ISIN & "%'" & _
     "AND urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription LIKE '%" & StlDate & "%' ) "
```

Answer (score 1):

Using "Option Compare Text" above your sub will allow you to search and find regardless of case. Try that and see if it solves it.